# Idiorm/Paris adds namespace name to my columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get Idiorm/Paris to work with my PHP-project. I have my table-objects located in a folder/namespace called project, when I try to run Idiorm/Paris it adds the "project"-name to the column.

> "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project_store_id' in 'where clause''"

`project_store_id` should be just `store_id`, anyone know how I can fix this? I suppose it tries to guess and it's almost correct, just don't want to manually fix this on everything.

Comment: But, are you ussing Paris or Idiorm??

Comment: Paris, sorry that I did not make that clear.

Comment: Can you show what code/command you are running to get this error?

Comment: The code is correct, I just need to tell Idiorm/Paris not to add namespace-class names as a prefix to my columnnames. :)

Comment: I am also quite sure that this is because of some sort of convention to keep objects organized, it would make sense if it was table names, but now I'm getting it on my column names.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the manual solution, ie telling which columns to use.

```
return $this->has_many('Project\Product', 'store_id', 'id');
```